# Can search within an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view with a tableview and a searchbar.
My tableview is filled with data take to SQLite, now i would add a searchbar.
Database fields are invoked through an object.

Receip.h

```
@interface Receip : NSObject {
    int ID; //id receip
    NSString *name;
    NSString *ingredients;
    NSString *detail;
    NSString *image; 
}
```

While my SearcViewController is:

```
#import "Receip.h"
#import "DBAccess.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation SearchViewController
@synthesize table,search, dataSource, tableData;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //initialize the two arrays; dataSource will be initialized and populated
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //  DBAccess object
    DBAccess *dbAccess = [[DBAccess alloc] init];
    // insert all recipes in the array
    dataSource = [dbAccess getAllRecipes];

    if ([dataSource count] > 0){
       [tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource];
       //on launch it should display all the records 
       [table reloadData];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
               reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Configure the cell.
    // Get the Receip object 
    Receip *receip = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = receip.name;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = receip.detail;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}


- (void) searchTableView {
    NSString *searchText = search.text;
    NSMutableArray *productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [dataSource count]; i++)
    {
        Receip *receip = [dataSource objectAtIndex:i];    
        NSString* sTemp = receip.name;
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText
                                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [productArray addObject:product];        
    } 
    [tableData release];
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:productArray];
    [productArray release];
}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
    if([searchText length] > 0) 
    {
        searchFlag = YES;
        [self searchTableView];
    }
    else 
    {
        searchFlag = NO;
    }
    [table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: yes its possible is it not working for u?

Comment: not work because i don't know search within object field

Answer (score 1):

ok, here u need to maintain 2 arrays. 1 for complete list 1 for searched list. Implement these methods

```
- (void) searchTableView 
{
    NSString *searchText = _searchBar.text;
    NSMutableArray *productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < [_productList count]; i++)
    {
       StoreProduct* product = [_productList objectAtIndex:i];    
        NSString* sTemp = product.name;
        NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText     options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [productArray addObject:product];        
    } 
    [_filteredArr release];
    _filteredArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:productArray];
   [productArray release];
}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if([searchText length] > 0) 
    {
        _searchFlag = YES;
        [self searchTableView];
    }
    else 
    {
        _searchFlag = NO;
    }
    [_catalogTableView reloadData];
}
```

and in cell for row method from _searchFlag u can come to know which array to be used, & u can get the objects in that.

Comment: Thk. I don't understand the use of _ReleaseObj(_filteredArr);
    _filteredArr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:productArray];

Comment: i have edited, the new array i have made is NSArray, just for maintaining NSArray i have alloc & initialize. The reason to release is since this method is called again & again am releasing the old searched list & filling again.

Comment: Ok, thk. Maybe i think that _filteredArray in the my code is tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; right?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get an error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS to [self searchTableView]

Comment: you might have released some object so this error, enable zombie & let me know the status of zombie

Comment: remove if ([dataSource count] > 0){
   [tableData addObjectsFromArray:dataSource];
   //on launch it should display all the records 
   [table reloadData];
} in viewDidLoad.. also show me cellForRow method.. with other dataSource methods of tableView

Comment: I have update my code. please see above. I can't remove this part if([dataSource count]>0)... because the tableview not loading the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6961/discussion-between-vishy-and-maurizio)